# Location of Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there any utiliy, that shows where the location of the module I have loaded.

Comment: Location?  You mean base memory address, or the file that the module was loaded from?

Comment: Location in memory where the module is loaded

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to know the base memory address for a module in the kernel's virtual address space, it can be found as the last field in `/proc/modules`; search for the module in question:

```
$ grep '^ext3' /proc/modules
ext3 125513 1 - Live 0xf88ce000
```

If you want to know the file path it was loaded from, the original path is not actually stored anywhere, but you can ask `modprobe` to search for the module again and display the path using `modprobe -l`:

```
$ /sbin/modprobe -l ext3
/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5PAE/kernel/fs/ext3/ext3.ko
```

Assuming you haven't changed anything in the module search path in the intervening time, this should give you the original load path.

EDIT:
As of 2015, the information isn't correct (not only that ext4 doesn't exist as a kernel module). Get information about the module, including the path of the image with:

`modinfo floppy`

Comment: Just a note: `cat /proc/modules` on Ubuntu 11.04 gives `Live 0x00000000` for all modules; however `sudo cat /proc/modules` does reveal actual addresses.

Answer (score 5):

No. This information is not retained when the module is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The information above isn't correct, for 2015.

modinfo will now give you information about the module. for example:
`modinfo floppy`

Comment: that's wrong, `modinfo` shows the location of the module "`floppy`" within the search path (basically in `/lib/modules` not the location from where the module "floppy" was loaded. In other terms it doesn't look at what is actually loaded but what exists on the disk at some predetermined locations.